# Linux kernel 6.6 from block_device how to find out if it has mounted file system

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, linux-kernel-headers

Prior to kernel 6.6, struct block_device had member variable:

```
struct super_block *    bd_super;
```

One could check if the block device had a mounted file system or not by checking:

```
struct super_block *sb = bdev->bd_super;
if (!sb) {
       // block device is not mounted.
}
```

But from kernel 6.6., struct block_device doesnt has the member variable: bd_super. Now how to check if the block _device has a mounted file system or not?

Comment: Indeed that was removed based on item 1 [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=511fb5bafed197ff76d9adf5448de67f1d0558ae), which also claims: `For all relevant places we have other means to get the same information`, but I'm not sure what this means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I found the superblock of a file system can be accessed from block_device using below cod:

```
struct super_block *sb = bdev->bd_holder;
```

I've confirmed this with vfst, ext2,3,4, xfs file systems.